# route path with ? and = on react router instead of /?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to make a react router path that will match this location:

http://localhost:8080/?grsf_window=true&grsf_cid=0v4rrc&grsf_ccid=wbc0eo

my Route path is like this, but it's not matching the location above:

```
<Route path={`/?grsf_window=:windowStatus&grsf_cid=:cid&grsf_ccid=:ccid`} component={Subscribe} />
```

help?

Comment: The path you want to match is `/`, the rest are query params, and `Route` is not concerned with them

Comment: I didn't know query params, i will add that on my research, thanks, hope it helps

Comment: you can access the query params with `location.search`, react router doesn't have any libraries to parse query strings but leaves the door open for you to select whichever you want

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be '/' everything else are optional parameters and react router is not at all concerned about that.

and in Subscribe component itself add a api call with those query strings